# Understanding SerializedPropertyType?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am creating a generic class that requires me to check the `SerializedPropertyType` of it's fields, and for the most part I know what each value of `SerializedPropertyType` means, but there are two values that I do not, and the API Documentation provides no useable information, the two values in question are `SerializedPropertyType.ManagedReference`, and `SerializedPropertyType.FixedBufferSize`.

The page for `ManagedReference` states "Managed reference property." as the description and for `FixedBufferSize` it states "Fixed buffer size property.", neither of which tell me what those types are used for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's documentation can be annoying when finding specific doc pages. For the managed property, [`here`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SerializedPropertyType.ManagedReference.html) is a useful doc page. And in case Unity decides to remove that page, it reads

> Represents a property that references an object that does not derive
> from UnityEngine.Object.
>
> This type is for fields that have the SerializeReference attribute,
> otherwise the object is stored inline
> (SerializedPropertyType.Generic).

As for FixedBufferSize, I could only find moderately helpful documentation and it is for [`SerializedProperty.fixedBufferSize`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty-fixedBufferSize.html), not SerializedPropertyType. I believe the `fixedBufferSize` is referring to a fixed buffer struct in C#, which you can read about [`here`](https://thedeveloperblog.com/fixed-buffer). The size is just a quick lookup for the physical size of the buffer - [`how many elements`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/c84064be69f20dcf21ebe4a7bbc176d48e2f289c/Editor/Mono/SerializedProperty.bindings.cs#L1930) are contained in this buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The concrete problem is not clear. To receive help I would try to narrow down the problem along with a code snippet with your attempt and where you're stuck at.
In case its of any help regarding "I don't know what a couple of the types refer to, and the documentation does not explain very well what I need to know about the type", what you need to know is that unity handles the serialization itself to show the fields in the inspector, let you program the editor UI etc, so you need to check [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html#ClassSerialized) to check what classes are serializable in unity.

Very probably for your case you need to check how to custom serialize your class. The first step is how to program a simple serializable class inheriting from the [Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html) class, and from there maybe move on to more complex cases.

Check also maybe if there is already something done to be used or inspire you. [this](https://github.com/azixMcAze/Unity-SerializableDictionary/blob/master/Assets/SerializableDictionary/SerializableDictionary.cs) might be useful.

Comment: I've updated my question, and hopefully what I am asking is more clear.